# bash not working correctly with org-babel on remote server

Tags: bash, org-mode, org-babel

The title is maybe too vague and too specific at the same time, so here is a more precise description.

I opened a remote file in Emacs with Tramp, and I wrote some org-babel blocks with bash headers, and it seemed that bash had been loaded, because when I do `echo $0` I got `bash` as return value. However I'm not sure `.bashrc` is properly loaded, because I had configured `conda` in my `.bashrc` file but when I do `which conda`, the block returned nothing, and a Babel error buffer popped up. So I guess bash was using some wrong configuration?

I also tried `which git`, since Git is not configured in the `.bashrc` file, I've gotten the correct return. And I've also run the same code blocks on my local machine, and on the remote machine but in the inferior bash shell, both worked as expected.

Here are the commands I've run and the results I'm getting. The `PATH` variable has different values when run in a orgbabel block and when run in the inferior shell.

```
#+begin_src bash
echo $0
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bash

#+begin_src bash
which conda
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+begin_src bash
. ~/.bashrc
which conda
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

#+begin_src bash
which git
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /usr/bin/git

#+begin_src bash
echo $PATH
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

The conda folder is not in PATH. However in the inferior bash shell when I run `echo $PATH` I got a different result (path to conda is included so I guess the rc file is properly sourced).

```
/home/bins/autodockvina/bin:/home/bins/ADFRsuite_x86_64Linux_1.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/home/bins:/root/anaconda3/bin:/root/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

So I guess the `.bashrc` file is not properly sourced in the orgbabel blocks?

I should probably add that I'm not quite sure how the different headers for shell blocks work, like `shell`, `sh`, and `bash`, etc.

Comment: If bash is running non-interactively (ie. a script) it will not source `.bashrc`. You can do `. ~/.bashrc` to source it. Or call commands by full path, or manually add paths to PATH, etc. Maybe try `hostname` also?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention it but the conda folder is already in PATH, so I don't understand why `which conda` is returning nothing, and I'm seeing a babel error buffer popping up.

Comment: I might be looking for the solution at the wrong directions... If the folder is already in PATH, I guess the command should work even if `.bashrc` is not sourced? So this might not be a problem with the rc file at all.

Comment: If `echo "$PATH"` prints the required path, and the executable file is in that path, then yes, under normal shell circumstances you can invoke the command. You could try a full path `/path/to/cmd`.

Comment: To ensure your `~/.bashrc` is loaded, even on remote access, you can source `.bashrc` in `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_provile` depending on distro). Some distros keep a `PROFILEREAD` variable associated with each login, so regardless how many subshells are spawned, the `.bashrc` is only read once. That's one option if it is a `.bashrc` problem. Where is your `PATH` being set if not in `.bashrc`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not quite sure how PATH is set, and I think that's the problem. I'll update the main body of the question.

Comment: @dan `echo "$PATH"` prints the required path when run in the inferior shell, but not when in the org-babel block. So I think I didn't source it correctly?